# postioning elements using percentage

Tags: jquery, css

Hi all am trying to position some elements using percentage which are defined as        `position:absolute` but the position are collapsed with each other on different screens  because of percentages.how should i get this by using percentage here my [demo](http://www.mediaserveit.com/demo/vivek/trans_test/) am trying to get it while on load the document

here my sample code

```
<div class="_onload">
    <span id="l-1">A</span>
    <span id="l-2">B</span>
</div>
```

style sheet

```css
._onload {
    background-color:#f00;
    display:none;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#l-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top:-85%;
    right:15.818%;
}
#l-2 {
    position: absolute;
    left:84.856%;
    bottom:-13.386%;
}
```

my js fot it

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('._onload').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('._onload #l-1').css("top", "85%");
    $('._onload #l-2').css("left", "84.102%");
});
```

here my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vivekranth/PhP97/8/)

Comment: How should the output look? It's doing exactly what you're telling it to at the moment.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the letter's positions are change for some small screen's and all

Comment: That's a given because they are aligned by % of screen size, .: they will change as the screen res does. You need to give them a fixed position using `px`, `em` or some other deterministic measurement.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan for exam it came correctly in 1920px widh screens but aligned wrongly on 1380px screens

Comment: oh yea! let me try :)

Answer (score 0):

I put the characters in a separate div and positioned that absolute. Then I removed the absolute positioning on the characters. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fred02138/7ZZgz/1/

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="_onload">
    <div id="text">
        <span id="l-1">A</span>
        <span id="l-2">B</span>
        <span id="l-3">C</span>
        <span id="l-4">D</span>
        <span id="l-5">E</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: if it made with your cover #text means the transistion effect won't appear.i think his ultimate goal is transistion

Comment: @VIVEk Yes, correct. But once you have those spans in a positioned div, you can position them with absolute px values rather than percentages to get the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You must use media queries, check this out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using percentage, you should use media queries, it's a good practice question.

See the W3C recommendation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) and some examples of use [here](http://mediaqueri.es/).